# Can someone help me convert this OBJ-C code to Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, facebook-audience-network

Im trying to add the facebook audience network to my project but the tutorial is in objective C and I need it in swift. I already made the bridging header, now I need to add the code. Can someone convert it to swift for me? Thank you! Heres the link if you want to take a look at it:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/ios/banner

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

     FBAdView *adView = [[FBAdView alloc] initWithPlacementID:PLACEMENT_ID adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner rootViewController:self];
     [adView loadAd];
     [self.view addSubview:adView];
 }
```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble converting to Swift? It seems like straightforward code.

Comment: Whats wrong with my question and why did I get downvoted?

Comment: You are just asking people to do work for you: "Please convert this code for me". Stack Overflow isn't a free work site, it is a help site. For people to be helping you, you need to indicate a problem, ideally with some failed effort of yours that needs fixing. Your real problem here is that you do not know how to write Swift code, but you want Swift code. The only solution would be to go learn Swift syntax.

Comment: I know how to write swift code. I don't know objective C. Thats the whole reason I put the question up. I also tried converting the code on my own and I couldnt figure it out so I posted it here.

Comment: If you tried converting it, you should post that attempt next time. It would indicate effort on your part and it would give people something to reference when helping you.

Comment: Language translation is off-topic for StackOverflow (see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825/code-translation-tagging). Please reframe as a Swift question focused on the problem you are trying to solve (in English), what you have done so far, what you expect your code to do, and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Ill fix it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work, let me know if any trouble

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let adView: FBAdView = FBAdView(placementID:PLACEMENT_ID, adSize:kFBAdSizeHeight50Banner, rootViewController:self);
    adView.loadAd();
    self.view.addSubview(adView);
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying expected decleration for the last two lines of code.